# How to Programmatically trigger focus() on Material UI Select field?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My app forms utilize the enter button to tab to specified fields for speed on a ten-key keyboard. When enter is hit, we do a DOM lookup and trigger focus() on the next element. This works great on text fields but I cannot understand how to accomplish this on a Select box in Material UI Beta@1.0.0-beta.21. I can get each of the DOM elements that make up the Select structure, but triggering focus() at any level does nothing.
Note: I am able to grab the ref of the item via inputRef on the select to prevent us from traversing the DOM but it still yields no results.

Question on GitHub: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/9182#issuecomment-345148074

Code Sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/m43qqyo2zy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `node` passed to `Select.props.inputRef()` references a hidden `input`. You would need to `focus()` on the `div` that is rendered as its sibling. Also, you need to handle the `Select` element case first in `handleKeyPressInternal()` because `getElementsByName()` will return the `input`.

This doesn't feel right, though, because you are relying on `Select` to render the focusable `div` as its immediate sibling. Could be grounds to extend `inputRef()` on `Select` to return the node that can visually receive focus.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zooz41oo3

Comment: Ahh thank you for the help. I tried doing a focus() on the div's at every level in it's DOM tree but I had not tried .previousSibling (too many years of using jQuery I suppose). I will investigate further and see if I can solidify the div to focus on in case the DOM structure changes for Select, specially since I am using Material UI beta.

Comment: Demo looks broken